# Weird NSPredicate Behavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have an NSPredicate which checks the relationship of an entity called "Eval(whosEval)" and if the relationship whosEval matches the full name of another entity, "Athlete(evals)", with the athlete that was selected, it displays all the Evals for that particular Athlete. Unfortunately, my predicate is doing weird things. If I have no athletes, and then add one, then add an eval, it shows all their evals, then I add another, the second athlete won't display any evals I added for that athlete and instead displays all of the other athlete's evals. Am I doing something incorrectly? All evals view controller is displayed prior to add Eval view controller.

allEvals.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Evaluations",_athletesFullName];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSFetchRequest *athleteRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [athleteRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
    NSError *athleteError = nil;
    NSPredicate *athletePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full == %@", _athletesFullName];
    [athleteRequest setPredicate:athletePredicate];
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:athleteRequest error:&athleteError];
    Athlete *currentAthlete = [results objectAtIndex:0];

   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosEval == %@", currentAthlete];
   [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSEntityDescription *eval = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Eval" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:eval];



    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date_recorded"
                                ascending:NO
                                 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //handle error
    }

    [self setEvalArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

addEval.m

```
-(void)saveEval{

//insert saving attributes here
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full == %@", _whichAthletesEval];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
        NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        Athlete *currentAthlete = [results objectAtIndex:0];

         [eval setWhosEval:currentAthlete];
        NSLog(@"This Eval Belongs to: %@",eval.whosEval);
        NSLog(@"whichAthletesEval value is equal to: %@", _whichAthletesEval);
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![_managedObjectContext save:&error]){
        //handle dat error
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have left inline comments (signed off with my initials) in your `viewWillAppear:` method that point out what I believe to be errors. Essentially, you fetch an arbitrary athlete instead of the one that's been selected (which I'm assuming is the source of `_athletesFullName`. As far as your `saveEval` method, your naming conventions are tough to follow so it's not clear to me what further issues you could have here.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Evaluations",_athletesFullName];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSFetchRequest *athleteRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [athleteRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
    NSError *athleteError = nil;
    // No predicate is used at all for the contents of results here - see below - CV
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:athleteRequest error:&athleteError];
    NSPredicate *athletePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full == %@", _athletesFullName];
    // This predicate never used as another predicate is set a few lines below - CV
    [request setPredicate:athletePredicate];
    // currentAthlete will not necessarily be the one conforming to athletePredicate
    // just the first in the array of every Athlete you've fetched - CV
    Athlete *currentAthlete = [results objectAtIndex:0];

    // because currentAthlete is arbitrary, you're now creating a predicate you likely didn't intend to - CV
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosEval == %@", currentAthlete];
   [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSEntityDescription *eval = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Eval" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:eval];



    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date_recorded"
                                ascending:NO
                                 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //handle error
    }

    [self setEvalArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: I think you are correct. What I meant to do was search all my athletes for the one that matches a property set with the athlete that was selected (fullname, the attribute under athlete is "full"), but I think I did it incorrectly?

Comment: I guess my main question is where did you get the full name from? It seems that ideally when one selects an Athlete that the object should just be passed directly to this view controller rather than just the athlete's name. That would eliminate the need for fetching. But there may be something else going on that's not clear that would preclude that approach. And yes, you didn't do it correctly - you create `athleteRequest`, set the entity, and then do the fetch without ever setting the predicate (in case my comments didn't make that clear).

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much!! I'll update my code in the question and accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: So basically, there were 2 errors. First was that I had a correct predicate, I just set it on the wrong request. I put request(which is the eval request) instead of athleteRequest, and then I fetched before setting the predicate. The updated code now works correctly. thanks again.

Comment: oh and i passed the full name from the athlete table view as the athlete was selected, i set a property in the next view controller with the athlete attribute for full name. it was a string property.

Comment: @user2674329 What I meant is where did you get the name from the place it was selected? I'm saying if you had the name then presumably you had the Athlete object itself, so ideally you could just pass that instead of the name, does that make sense? Also, why did you edit your question to include the corrected code?

Comment: sorry, im new to stackoverflow, i thought thats what you did. But this is what I do, the root view is a tableview of ALL athletes. when you select an athlete, it passes the athlete.full into a property I created on the allevals view which is the next view controller pushed. So in the allevals, it only shows the evals for the athlete that was selected using this property that was set via the didselectatrowindexpath method. Could you further explain what you meant by passing the athlete itself?

Comment: @user2674329 I'm saying, don't pass athlete.full into allevals, just pass athlete. allEvals could then not have any code in it to fetch an athlete. As it is, you take an athlete object, pass its full name to another view controller, which then has to go and fetch that same athlete again, it just seems like extra code / trouble.

Comment: @user2674329 But, that's just a suggestion.

Comment: I will definitely do that. I'm only 16 and just started iOS programming this month so I apologize if i'm not that great with the whole OOP logic yet. But yes, I can see how that would be beneficial and I will do that. Thanks for your support.